# Installation for pyzmq for Windows fails with error C2143, C4142

Tags: python, windows, pyzmq

I have a windows 7 machine with python 2.7 and I am trying to install `pyzmq` following [these](http://zeromq.org/docs:windows-installations) steps. I built `libzmq` got the binaries and copied them from `libzmq\bin\Win32\Debug\v140\dynamic\` to `libzmq\lib\` so the next step will work(compiler will have access to /lib and /includes from the same parent folder). But, on this step:

> $ python setup.py configure --zmq=../libzmq

I installed `pyzmq` and `libzmq` on the same parent folder, as in the installation description related to `pyzmq`, `libzmq` is here: `../libzmq`

But when I need to configure the `pyzmq`, I get this error: 
[image]

I have VS Community 2015 installed and everything seems fine.

Comment: Try `python -m pip install pyzmq`

Answer (score 0):

ZMQ usually provides `sln` files that will build from Microsoft Visual Studio. You will have to dig around a little to find it. You are better off trying to get that to work then going directly from the  `python setup.py` that you are currently attempting. Note that you also need `libsodium` to be built and installed. Thankfully, they also provide Microsoft `sln` files.

In any case, you are probably better using one of the Python wheels like those from Christoph http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Just do

`pip install <wheel file>`

and you should be good.

Good luck!